# AS- P1 differentiation (gradients)

Tags: derivatives

The curve with the equation y= ax^2 +bx +c passes through the point (1,2). The gradient of the curve is zero at the point (2,1). find the values of a, b and c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You are given that the points (1,2) and (2,1) are on the curve. This gives you two equations in terms of $a,b,c$ already. Then compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$. You are given that this is zero when $x=2$, so with this, you get another equation in terms of $a,b,c$. Then solve these simultaneously. Can you do this?

Comment: got it..thank you :)

Comment: @wizard No worries!